# LDAP directory design considerations

Tags: design-patterns, ldap

In an organization, every employee uses several services, and so I've decided to use an OpenLDAP server to store the user-related information in one centralized location (which presently is not the case, causing a lot of headache). After reading a couple of books and countless texts online, I still can't make up my mind between two design approaches.

**1.**
To put people's minimal personal data (names, phones, e-mails) under ou=people,dc=example,dc=com, and the application-specific entries into separate subtrees, linking them to users via DN-s. Like, for instance, a separate subtree for e-mail with aliases, quotas, etc.; a separate subtree for PBX credentials, and so on. This way the application access is more straightforward. On the other hand, the same information is repeated in different subtrees: a user's e-mail and uid under "ou=people,dc=example,dc=com", and a mailbox record linking an e-mail address to user's mailbox (which happens to coincide with user's uid).

**2.**
A different approach, also seen in some tutorials, is to stuff the application-related personal data into person's object using auxiliary classes, like here:

http://www.watersprings.org/pub/id/draft-srivastava-ldap-mail-00.txt

with the actual schema here:

http://www.netfrag.org/webnews/article.php?id=89&group=nfo.links.computing

It feels that the first approach is more reasonable, but as it is my first serious LDAP directory implementation with a lot of users involved, I'd rather ask an advice from more experienced LDAP-ers.

My apologies for probably too general question.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the above.

The first idea is just terrible design. Would you put all your floating point columns into a single table in a database?

The second idea uses an Internet Draft that expired nearly 13 years ago. There's a reason why it never became an RFC.

Use the `inetOrgPerson` object class, and stick everything in there. Use the directory to express directory structure, e.g. Users, Groups, Roles, ... not to isolate datatypes as per your first idea.

Comment: Thanks for a sobering reply :).

"Would you put all your floating point columns into a single table in a database?"

Hardly. However, I would consider splitting the data that is intensively used in complex searches and data containing large entries.

The "terrible" idea is not about isolating data types, rather about organizing data objects trees according to how they are supposed to be used. Postfix won't be interested in a person's phone number, and an employee looking up another employee's phone number will hardly be interested in her mail quota used.

Comment: @badbishop It remains a terrible idea, a really strange way to organize an LDAP directory. Mostly they are organized to mirror the organization structure, which is also a terrible idea for another reason, or along the lines I suggested above, i.e. functionally.